# Does Quran 5:45 "an eye for an eye ..." rule apply to muslims?

Tags: quran, hadith, jews, torah

Translation of [Quran 5:45](https://legacy.quran.com/5/45) by "Sahih International" trio (Emily Assami, Amatullah Bantley, Mary Kennedy):

> And We ordained for them therein a life for a life, an eye for an eye,
>   a nose for a nose, an ear for an ear, a tooth for a tooth, and for
>   wounds is legal retribution. But whoever gives [up his right as]
>   charity, it is an expiation for him. And whoever does not judge by
>   what Allah has revealed - then it is those who are the wrongdoers.

"for them" - this is about Jews. As i know, this rule also applies to Muslims. (for example, in [Does "whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed" (Qur'an 5:45) only apply to judges (qadi)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45944) you can see that).

But how do I know that this indeed applies also to Muslims? maybe there are hadith which clearly say that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verse is elaborating *Qisas* (retribution), and *Qisas* has also been explicitly ordained for us:

> يا أيها الذين آمنوا كتب عليكم القصاص في القتلى
>
> O you who have believed, prescribed for you is legal retribution for those murdered
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:178](http://quran.com/2/178)</sup>

> والحرمات قصاص فمن اعتدى عليكم فاعتدوا عليه بمثل ما اعتدى عليكم
>
> And for [all] violations is legal retribution. So whoever has assaulted you, then assault him in the same way that he has assaulted you.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:194](http://quran.com/2/194)</sup>

> أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قضى بالقصاص في السن وقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم كتاب الله القصاص ‏
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ ruled that Qisas should be given for a tooth. The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said: "What Allah has decreed is retaliation."
>
> <sup>— [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai/45/47), [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/53/13), [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/28/33)</sup>

Also, it is part of the Usul of many madhabs that when a law of the previous Shariah is chronicled in the Quran and there is no evidence of it being abrogated, then such laws are not abrogated and the command extends to us as well:

> شرع لكم من الدين ما وصى به نوحا والذي أوحينا إليك وما وصينا به إبراهيم وموسى وعيسى
>
> He has ordained for you of religion what He enjoined upon Noah and that which We have revealed to you, [O Muhammad], and what We enjoined upon Abraham and Moses and Jesus
>
> <sup>— [Quran 42:13](http://quran.com/42/13)</sup>

> أولئك الذين هدى الله فبهداهم اقتده
>
> Those are the ones whom Allah has guided, so from their guidance take an example.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:90](http://quran.com/6/90)</sup>

Answer (score -5):

This is one of The Law that Allah gave to Moses. There is no "them", The Law has been made eternal from the day of creation for ALL LIVING BEING. Even animals have law and punishment to ordain.

"Them" has been misguided by Sunni scholar to keep hating on jews. ALL LAW apply to all human because Jew will arise as the light of the world and we will follow them.

If men strive, and hurt a woman with child, so that her fruit depart from her, and yet no mischief follow: he shall be surely punished, according as the woman's husband will lay upon him; and he shall pay as the judges determine. And if any mischief follow, then thou shalt give life for life, Eye for eye, tooth for tooth, hand for hand, foot for foot, Burning for burning, wound for wound, stripe for stripe.
Exodus:21:22-25

And he that blasphemeth the name of the LORD, he shall surely be put to death, and all the congregation shall certainly stone him: as well the stranger, as he that is born in the land, when he blasphemeth the name of the Lord, shall be put to death. And he that killeth any man shall surely be put to death. And he that killeth a beast shall make it good; beast for beast. And if a man cause a blemish in his neighbor; as he hath done, so shall it be done to him; Breach for breach, eye for eye, tooth for tooth: as he hath caused a blemish in a man, so shall it be done to him again. And he that killeth a beast, he shall restore it: and he that killeth a man, he shall be put to death. Ye shall have one manner of law, as well for the stranger, as for one of your own country: for I am the LORD your God.
Leviticus:24:16-22